# Set a cookie via CURL (php)

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

Is is possible to create a cookie / session via cURL? I'm sending login data via cURL to a wordpress file and if the data are correct I want to login the user. Is there a way to do that? My curl file looks like this:

```
    $url = 'http://www.domain.de/blog/wordpress-dosomething.php?username=[username]&password=[password]&rememberMe=[rememberMe]'; 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    $rsp = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

And my wordpress file looks like this:

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$password = $_GET['password'];
//login the user
$user = wp_signon( array('user_login' => $username, 'user_password' => $password, 'remember' => $remember), false );
if ( is_wp_error($user) )
  //error...
```

If I test this by calling the wordpress file manually, this works and I'm logged in to wordpress. But via curl it doesn't work, even though there is no error, so how can I make this work? Can I somehow... I don't know... catch the session/cookie set by my script and manually set it in my curl Script file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible answer http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36452/creating-login-session-via-curl

Comment: You should include username and password in your url, since you are sending `GET` request

Comment: open cookie.txt file. Do you see anything written in that file?

Comment: yes, there are 3 lines with cookie data

Comment: What is the value for `CURLOPT_URL`

Comment: I will edit the question to show you the value of curlopt_url

Answer (score 1):

You could set cookie through the CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR and CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE options of curl in PHP. Example:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookieFilePath);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookieFilePath);
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Then the cookie content will be automatically saved in the $cookieFilePath, which is a local file path.

Comment: do I have to do something with the $cookieFilePath ? If I understand that correctly the cookie is written to $cookieFilePath, but I'm still not logged in, so how do I continue with this?

Comment: Note that, you shoud send your username and password in the login request url. You don not need to deal with the $cookieFilePath. Just set the two options in every request. The cookie file will be read and written automatically.

Comment: I did and the script even checks for correct username and password and they ARE correct... so the submission of username and password is not the problem

Answer (score 1):

Add `COOKIEFILE` and `COOKIEJAR` as option and a text file named cookie.txt in your aplication directory

```
$cookie_file=realpath('cookie.txt');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file);
$rsp = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

hope this will help

Comment: adding that didn't change anything, do I have to add something else?

Comment: You should include username and password in your url, since you are sending `GET` request

Comment: username and password are sent via $url, those are included